# Memory Efficient Methods To Find Unique Strings

Tags: c++, algorithm, string, data-structures

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
000 100 200 300 010 020 030 001 002 003     
001 101 201 301 011 021 031 000 002 003    
002 102 202 302 012 022 032 001 000 003    
003 103 203 303 013 023 033 001 002 000    
010 110 210 310 000 020 030 011 012 013     
020 120 220 320 010 000 030 021 022 023     
030 130 230 330 010 020 000 031 032 033     
033 133 233 333 013 023 003 031 032 030     
100 000 200 300 110 120 130 101 102 103     
133 033 233 333 113 123 103 131 132 130     
200 100 000 300 210 220 230 201 202 203     
233 133 033 333 213 223 203 231 232 230     
300 100 200 000 310 320 330 301 302 303     
303 103 203 003 313 323 333 301 302 300     
313 113 213 013 303 323 333 311 312 310     
330 130 230 030 310 320 300 331 332 333    
331 131 231 031 311 321 301 330 332 333    
332 132 232 032 312 322 302 331 330 333    
333 133 233 033 313 323 303 331 332 330
```

What I intend to do is to generate list of unique strings from it, yielding:

```
000
001
002
003                      
010
011
012
013
020
021
022
023
030
031
032
033
100
101
102
103
110
113
120
123
130
131
132
133
200
201
202
203
210
213
220
223
230
231
232
233
300
301
302
303
310
311
312
313
320
321
322                      
323
330
331      
332      
333
```

The code I have to generate that is this. But it is very memory consumptive.
Because in reality the string is of length >36 and there are more than 35 million 
lines in a file. Each line with >36*3 number of columns/entries. 
Is there a memory efficient way to do it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;


int main  ( int arg_count, char *arg_vec[] ) {
    if (arg_count !=2 ) {
        cerr << "expected one argument" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;      
    }

    string line;
    ifstream myfile (arg_vec[1]);


     map <string,int> Tags;    

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile,line) )
        {
            stringstream ss(line);    
            string Elem;


            while (ss >> Elem) {      

                Tags[Elem] = 1;           

            }


        }
        myfile.close();  
    }
    else { cout << "Unable to open file";} 


   for (map <string,int>::iterator iter = Tags.begin(); iter !=
           Tags.end();iter++) {      
       cout << (*iter).first << endl; 
   }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A pity that you need to do it in c++. It's so easy as a shell script: "sed -e 's/ /\n/g' filename | sort -u"

Comment: Are the strings in a file of a same fixed length ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends a bit on the characteristics of your dataset. In the worse case, where all strings are unique, you will need either O(n) memory to record your seen-set, or O(n^2) time to re-scan the entire file on each word. However, there are improvements that can be made.

First off, if your dataset only consists of 3-digit integers, then a simple array of 1000 bools will be much more memory effieicnt than a map.

If you're using general data, then another good approach would be to sort the set, so copies of the same string end up adjacent, then simply remove adjacent words. There are well-researched algorithms for [sorting a dataset too large to fit in memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). This is most effective when a large percentage of the words in the set are unique, and thus holding a set of seen words in memory is prohibitively expensive.

Incidentally, this can be implemented easily with a shell pipeline, as GNU sort does the external sort for you:

```
tr " " "\n" < testdata | LC_ALL=C sort | uniq
```

Passing LC_ALL=C to sort disables locale processing and multibyte character set support, which can give a significant speed boost here.

Comment: Note that 'sort -u' can be more efficient than 'sort | uniq'. That's what I was about to post as an answer.

Comment: Ah, nice, didn't know about -u. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 4):

**O(1) memory [ram]:**

If you want to use no memory at all (besides a couple temp variables) you could simply read 1 entry at a time and add it to the output file if it doesn't already exist in the output file.    This would be slower on time though since you'd have to read 1 entry at a time from the output file.

You could insert the entry into the output file in alphabetical order though and then you would be able to see if the entry already exists or not in O(logn) time via binary search per entry being inserted.  To actually insert you need to re-create the file though which is O(nlogn).  You do this n times for each input string, so overall the algorithm would run in O(n^2logn) (which includes lookup to find insertion pos + insertion) and use O(1) RAM memory.

Since your output file is already in alphabetical order though future lookups would also only be O(logn) via binary search.

You could also minimize the re-creation phase of the file by leaving excessive space between entries in the file.  WHen the algorithm was done you could do a vacuum on the file.  This would bring it down to O(nlogn).

---

**Another way to reduce memory:**

If it's common that your strings share common prefixes then you can use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and probably use less memory overall since you mentioned your strings are > length 36.  This would still use a lot of memory though.

Comment: Inserting in alphabetical order requires sorting properly first (O(n) storage, on disk or in RAM) - and then you need only compare against the prior entry each time.

Comment: Ya O(1) RAM usage but O(n) disk usage. I'm assuming that you insert in alphabetical order each time to the file. But this requires you to re-write the file each time unfortunately because you can't just insert into the middle of the file.  So each lookup is O(logn) but each insertion is O(nlogn) and for the whole file it is O(n^2logn).

Comment: Insertion sort is O(n^2), unless you're using a file format such as a B*tree to effectively do an on-disk sort - in which case I'd expect just doing a normal external sort to be much more efficient (due to less seeking) unless the proportion of uniques is very low.

Comment: Good points about storing with a smart file format and also about it not being so bad if you have not a lot of unique entries.

Answer (score 3):

Well, std::set might be slightly faster and use less memory than std::map.

Answer (score 2):

It seems given that large number of entries, there will be a reasonable amount of overlap in the sequences of symbols. You could build tree using the entries at each position each sequence as nodes. Say you have an entry 12345 and 12346  then the first four entries in the sequence overlap and thus could be stored in a tree with 6 nodes.

You could walk the tree to see if a given symbol is contained at a given position, if not you would add it. When you reach the end of the given string you would just mark that node as terminating a string node. Reproducing the unique entries would be a matter of a depth first traversal of the tree the path from the root node to each terminator represents a unique entry.

If you partition the dataset, say into X thousand line chunks and aggregate the trees it would make a nice map-reduce job.

You're looking at a node space of 10^36 so if the data is entirely random you're looking at a large possible number of nodes. If there's a good deal of overlap and a smaller number of unique entries you will probably find you use a good deal less

Comment: +1 for you. You beat me to it. I was going to suggest the exact same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just write an in-place sort for it. You're still going to have to load the file to memory though, because in-place sorting with IO wouldn't be efficient. You'd have to read and write for every comparison.

Comment: Sorting with IO is obviously less efficient than in-memory sorting, but it can use a heck of a lot less memory if you're willing to make the tradeoff. Google "external sort" - there are a bunch of clever algorithms.

Comment: I'm sure there are, but the disk seek time on an O(1) algorithm performed on 10^36 values is still going to be ridiculous. Just put it in memory and sort it, I say.

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` would be better, but you should look into hash sets. Those are not available in the current C++ standard library (although it is supposed to be in C++0x's) but some compilers have implementations. Visual C++ has [stdext::hash_set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t4xas78(VS.80).aspx) and boost has some kind of stuff for this, see [Boost Multi-index Containers Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Comment: The C++0x name for these containers is `std::tr1::unordered_set`.  Recent versions of Microsoft and GNU C++ compilers (and probably others) have TR1 support out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Try STXXL as an external stl for huge datasets.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I would suggest is to use memory mapped file to access the data and radix sort to sort the list. This is trivial if the strings are of same length. 
If the strings are of different lengths, use radix sort for a fast presorting using the n first characters, then sort the unsorted sub lists with whatever method is most appropriate. With very short sublists, a simple bubble sort would do it. With longer lists use quick sort or use the STL set with a custom class providing the compare operator.

With memory mapping and radix sort, the memory requirement and performance would be optimal. All you need is the mapping space (~size of file) and a table of 32bit values with one value per string to hold the linked list for radix sort.

You could also save memory and speed up the sorting by using a more compact encoding of the strings. A simple encoding would use 2 bits per character, using values 1,2 and 3 for the three letters and 0 to signal the end of string. Or more efficient, use a base 3 encoding, packed into integers and encode the length of string in front. Let say you have characters c1, c2, C3, c4 the encoding would yield the integer c1*3^3 + c2*3^2 + c3*3^1 + c4*3^0. This suppose you assign a value from 0 to 2 to each character. By using this encoding you'll save memory and will optimize sorting if the number of strings to sort is huge.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the excellent library [Judy arrays](http://judy.sourceforge.net/). A compact trie based, very fast and memory efficient data structure witch scale to billons strings. Better than any search-tree.
You can use the JudySL functions to your purpose. You can use it similar to your program, but it is much faster and more memory efficient.